# create file with given name and permissions in linux using c

Tags: c, linux, file, permissions, chmod

I have to write a function in c create with 2 parameters: file name and permissions for the file. (e.g: create("f","rwxr_xr_x") this function creates file f which will receive "rwxr_xr_x" permissions and will return 0)If the file already exists or it can not be created it will return a number different from 0. 
Here is the code that I came up with:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

int create(char *name, char *mode)
{
    int fp = fopen(name, "r+");
    if (fp > 0)
    {
        int i, n = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < 9; i = i + 3)
        {
            int nr = 0;
            if (mode[i] == 'r')     nr += 4;
            if (mode[i + 1] == 'w') nr += 2;
            if (mode[i + 2] == 'x') nr += 1;
            n = n * 10 + nr;
        }
        chmod(name, n);
        return 0;
    }
    else
        return -1;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if (argc != 3) printf("%s\n", "Error: Incomplet number of arguments!");
    int fp;
    fp = create(argv[1], argv[2]);
    if (fp == 0) printf("%s\n", "File successfully created!");
    else printf("%s\n", "Could not create file!");
    return 0;
}
```

I tried to open the file in r+ mode and then I used chmod to change permissions, {not sure if this is correct). When I compile this, I get the following warning: "initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast for the line `int fp=fopen(name, r+)` . Can someone please help me solve this and tell me if the code is correct? I am new to linux

UPDATE
so I made some changes, as suggested but I think it still does not give the right permissions (as I said I am new to linux, so I might be wrong).  Here is how my code looks now:

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <stdio.h> 
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <sys/stat.h>
 #include <sys/types.h>
 #include <fcntl.h>
 int create(char *name, char *mode)
 {
  int i,n=0;
  for(i=0; i<9; i=i+3)
   {
      int nr=0;
      if(mode[i]=='r')   nr+=4;
      if(mode[i+1]=='w') nr+=2;
      if(mode[i+2]=='x') nr+=1;
      n=n*8+nr;
   }   
  int fl=creat(name, n);
  printf("%d\n", n); 
   if(fl>0)
       return 0;
   else return -1;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   if(argc != 3)
      printf("%s\n", "Error: Incomplet number of arguments!");

   int fp;
   fp=create(argv[1], argv[2]);
   if(fp==0) printf("%s\n", "File successfully created!");
   else printf("%s\n", "Could not create file!");
   return 0;
}
```

Also, how can I check if the file already exists? Because in that case my function has to return a value different from 0 and print an error message

Comment: `fopen`returns a `FILE *` not an int, `open` returns an `int`

Comment: @PawanKartik: Question is related to creating a file and not a directory.

Comment: @Alexandra_p: Any reason for not using [open/creat](https://linux.die.net/man/2/creat)?

Comment: ITYM `n = n * 8 + nr`, since you're working in octal there.

Comment: @TobySpeight thank you for your suggestion, I changed it but still not sure it works?

Comment: @TobySpeight for example let's take permissions rwxrwxrwx, nr=511, shouldn't the second parameter be 0777 in order to give the right permissions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly your problem with this line:

```
int fp=fopen(name, "r+");
```

`fopen` returns a value of type `FILE *` not `int` so that line should be

```
FILE *fp=fopen(name, "r+");
```

And that means you need to test if `fp` is not `NULL` not `> 0`.

Having created the file, you should also remember to call `fclose(fp)` to close the file as well.

Your code handling the permissions is also wrong. The values you normally pass to the `chmod` command in the shell are octal, not decimal, so this line is wrong.

```
n=n*10+nr;
```

You want to multiple `n` by 8 each time.

Since it's a bit field you could improve the code by using the '|=' operator to change the appropriate bits rather than using addition.

```
if(mode[i]=='r')   nr |=4;
if(mode[i+1]=='w') nr |=2;
if(mode[i+2]=='x') nr |=1;
```

Also you should really check to make sure that mode is at least 9 characters long before the loop.

Comment: thank you for your suggestios. but why multiply n by 8? I get that the second parameter has to be octal, but for example if we take rwxrwxrwx n=511, and shouldn't the second parameter be 0777? I tested this example with the n multiplied by 8 and for owner and group it sets the right permissions (read and write), but for others it appears read-only, when it should also be read and write?

Comment: @Alexandra_p if `n` is 511 (decimal) then that is the same as 0777 which is octal. If you multiple by 10, you'd get 777 which is 1411 in octal.

Comment: The reason why it's not working as you'd expect is because the mode is being affected by your umask - you'd still need to do a `chmod` to get the actual permissions you want.